# Create line, bar graphs using mysql database and php index script

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need your help here. I've been struggling to create charts with the sensor data i have in mysql database. I have 3 php files. 1 is the connection file to the database, 2 is the sensor documents that puts sensor data to the database, 3 is the index one which put the data from the database and put it in a form of a table. I have been struggling to create charts or maybe a dashboard with the data from the database. Anyone with an idea on how i can achieve this? I am new in this Web Development world so my research hasn't produced anything good to me.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by sensor data please explain it more and read out this chart js library there are also many graph libraries you can use.

**Chart.js**
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. I managed to draw a graph using Chart.js. Now i want to show at least 10 t0 20 data.My database has over 4000 values and so it's messing up the graph. Can't see what's what.Here's the link to the video i got guided by in this regard.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmz79gH0l6c&t=654s